# what is this kinds of object detection methodology based on deep learning?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

The task is to detect big circles and small black circles if big circles have small black circles like below picture (a left picture is an original picture and a right one is the detectec one).

I am trying to detect these circles using object detection based on deep learning.
To do this, my idea is to detect two circle at the same time using one object detection.

one methodology : by using just one object detector, big circles and small circles are detected.

Other one : first big circles are detected by using one object detector and then small circles are detected by using other detector. In other words, this is to use two object detection.

I am wondering about what is kinds of latter object detection methodology, which is to detect step by step?
Intuitively, I could call hierarchical object detection.
Please let me know what is this kinds of methodology. Thank you.

[image]